# HTTPError 596 when calling NYT times events api with urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to call the NYT events api with urllib2 but I'm receiving a 596 error. If I construct the url myself, there is no problem, but if I call urlopen with the data instead, I receive the 596 error. What's going on? The 596 error seems to be undocumented, so it doesn't help.

```
>>> data = urllib.urlencode({'api-key': os.environ['NYT_EVENT_LISTING_API_KEY']})  
>>> resp = urllib2.urlopen('?'.join([url,data]))
>>> resp = urllib2.urlopen(url, data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
response = meth(req, response)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp) 
HTTPError: HTTP Error 596:
```

Comment: If you catch the exception and call its `read()` method, you will get the HTTP response body.  Perhaps that will give you a clue about what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Thomas is right, you are using `GET` in your first request which will construct the URL to something like this:

```
nytimes.com/api/?MY_API_KEY
```

However, your second call to `urllib2.urlopen` sends the `data` as a `POST` request to this URL

```
nytimes.com/api/
```

instead, which gives you *596 service not found error*.

---

Now, `urllib2` is notorious for its non-intuitive API and documentation, you may consider using [`Requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org) instead:

```
import requests

api_key = {'api-key': os.environ['NYT_EVENT_LISTING_API_KEY']}
resp = requests.get(url, params=api_key)
print resp.text
print resp.json
```

This way, `GET` requests and `POST` requests are a lot easier to distinguish, url and parameters are separated as well.

Comment: Thanks, I wish I had known about requests earlier. It seems so much more intuitive.

Comment: @bschlueter I *love* Requests :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first request is a GET request - the second is a POST request. See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) on this - when the parameter `data` is provided, urlopen performs a POST request.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't thinking about the automatic change.